# How to repeat data using ngFor in multi-select dropdown in angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-multiselect

Iam working on angular project.I have a requirement of displaying a dropdown with multi-select option.I have used bootstrap multi-select dropdown for this purpose.It works fine for static data.When I am using an array and on repeating the array using ngFor,dropdown is not working.Here is my code:

```js
public citiesArray=["bangalore","chennai"];
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#city').multiselect({
      enableClickableOptGroups: true,
      enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true
  });
```

```html
  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select id="city">
                      <option>Select City</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let city of citiesArray" [value]="city">{{city}}</option>
                        <!-- <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
                        <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                        <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option> -->
                    </select>  
            </div>
```

How can I implement ngFor for bootstrap multi-select dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using ngAfterViewInit instead of document ready

```
public citiesArray = ["bangalore", "chennai"];

ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('#city').multiselect({
    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
    enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true
  })
}
```